# Css is not being applied when html is loaded via ajax call

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, codeigniter, model-view-controller

my controller code is

```
  public function search_results()
  {
    $data['product_select'] = $this->input->post('product_select');
    $this->load->view('public/search_results');
  }
```

and js code is

```
   $('#serch_btn').click(function(){
   let product_select = $("#product_select").val();
   console.log(product_select);
   $("#hide_content").hide();
   $.ajax({
       url:'<?php echo base_url() ?>public_controller/search_results',
       method:'post',
       dataType:'html',
       data:{product_select:product_select},
       success:function(data) {
        $('#show_content').html(data);
       }
     });
   });
```

html is being loaded but it's styles are not applied, like theme.css and other. I know a that css is loaded when page is loaded so when i make ajax call then css doesn't apply to the html loaded via ajax call. But i have done this in other project and it worked fine. In this I'm having trouble. How can i overcome this issue

Comment: Are you hoping that the css files from the page sent to the ajax will get loaded? If so jQuery ajax strips out anything in the head and you will need to include all needed styles in the main page

Comment: no what i want is to change one div in whole page. so that when i click on search button is shows that specific div. and html i showing ok but it's css not is applied

Comment: Without a [mcve] we have no idea why and can only guess but there are numerous possibilities involved

Comment: ok suggest me any solution

Comment: That's like trying to answer .... "why won't my car start?". Too many unknowns without a lot more specifics

Comment: it is advance serach so when i click on serach button shows html under a div with id show_content. so when i click the button it places html like paragraph and pic and button but it is simple html no css is applied

Comment: As previously mentioned make sure all relevant css is included in the main page

Comment: i have explained in my best way it is so simple and basic question. i think the problem is when i load html via ajax call then css needs to be reloaded to be applied on that html. i dont know how to do that without page refresh

Comment: yes all css is included in page.

Comment: Then perhaps the rules are not specific enough for the new elements. Again...far too many unknowns here. There is no one size fits all answer the same as asking why a car won't start

Comment: What charlietfl wants to ask: How does the html of search_result look like? What is the css that should be applied? (CSS is usually applied automatically so there has to be a logic error in your scenario that you didn't write about)

Comment: are you using response html for different project or same project ?

Comment: i am using for same project. what i mean is that i have done this search in many places i just simple load html from other file and show it in div but this time i dont know why i am stuck. becuase i am getting html successfully but css is not being applied like bootstrap is not applied when i load html via ajax call

Answer (score 0):

you need to return (echo) that view of your controller function `search_results()` as data, in order to receive it in the ajax success function and consequently to manipulate your DOM - without reloading the page.

Right now you are just loading a new view, that is without any other views you might have loaded previously together with this page and where you may have loaded the css file(s).

Instead of plane loading the view in your controller, you need to send it back as data via ajax:

```
  public function search_results()
  {
    $data['product_select'] = $this->input->post('product_select');
    echo $this->load->view('public/search_results', $data, true);
  }
```

see [Returning views as data](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/views.html#returning-views-as-data)

**debug hint:** place an alert() inside your ajax success and see if it's triggered

**P.S.:** If you have a style sheet in this view file, it would be the last in the cascade and apply to this view only.

Comment: i am getting html which means method is return view as data but on that html css is not applied. like bootstrap and theme.css

Comment: then, as mentioned in the comments,  the CSS rules might not be specific enough for the new elements.  make one custom rule in a custom.css and check it out, to debug, or apply the styles you need with a <style> element in the view

Comment: just one question i did this same process in this project and it worked fine

Comment: maybe i am missing something or there is some error. if there is error html should not be loaded and i tried ditto method to make it work but didn't .

Comment: then load the view which works in search_results(), and see the outcome

Comment: if i place html in page instead of loading via ajax it works fine

Comment: try using without data Type or use another dataType, I send all my stuff with dataType:'json', which works in the way I described above, but you need to echo it: `echo $this->load->view('public/search_results', $data, true);`please check

Comment: still same problem i tried but css is not being applied it's just loading html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213517/discussion-between-vickel-and-programmer).